# Plotting raster with just 2 pixels using levelplot function in "rasterVis" package in R

Tags: r, raster, levelplot, rastervis

I am trying to plot the following raster using the levelplot function in the "rasterVis) package, but all this gives me is a straight line. I tried to give different breaks to the legend using the "at"command but to no avail. I tried whatever I could in the documentation but couldnt find an answer. 
Also, the raster is plotting fine with the "plot()" and "image()" command in R. Kindly help.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
sr <- "+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
r <- raster(resolution =c(24600, 28900), crs = sr, nrows = 1, ncols = 2, ext = extent(c(573800, 623000, 3508713, 3537613)))
r[] <- c(1,2)
levelplot(r, margin = FALSE)
```

[plot of the output from levelplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU9Up.jpg)

**Edit 1**
When I define the raster with no extent and projection, then the raster plots fine with levelplot. I am unable to find the reason.

```
r2 <- raster(nrows =1, ncols =2)
r2[] <- c(1, 2)
levelplot(r2, margin = FALSE)
```

[plot of raster r2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2LUq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `resolution` is used, arguments `ncols` and `nrows` are ignored. Remove `resolution` and `nrow` to plot it with `levelplot`.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
sr <- "+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
r <- raster(ncol = 2, crs = sr, ext = extent(c(573800, 623000, 3508713, 3537613)))
r[] <- c(1, 2)
levelplot(r, margin = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much.

Comment: Could you [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it answers your question? :-)

Comment: @Stephan: I just did..sorry am new to Stackoverflow...thankyou for helping me out